# Network Connection Error with Ubuntu 22.04 after rebooting

Tags: network-manager, internet

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 version. After rebooting computer, network connection failed. I've tried all possibilities as I know, check network cable(changed with other cable which properly works), check LAN card, etc.

Although checking the network settings, wired connection is connected with 100Mb/s but the network image on top right side seems not connected with question mark on it.